# DatagramSocket connection in Spring 4 Java config

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-mvc, udpclient

I am building a web application using `spring 4 web-mvc` framework with `spring security` enabled. Now I need make a `socket` connection with another server for getting some data.

Each logged in user will have a separated socket connection to that other server.

How can I do this???

Should I run separate thread for each user or does spring has any mechanism for continuously receiving packet through `socket`??

I googled for this but couldn't find suitable answer and most of the answers are xml based. But I need `java based config`.

Please post answer with pseudo code if possible or point me to the right URL.

this is what i am doing now

```
DatagramSocket serverSocket;
String receiveString = null;
byte[] received_bytes = new byte[ServerConstants.BUFFER_SIZE];
DatagramPacket received_packet = new DatagramPacket(received_bytes, received_bytes.length);
serverCommunication.getServerSocket().receive(received_packet);
received_bytes = received_packet.getData();
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection. What is your *real* question?

Comment: please see the modified question. sorry for the mess up. please let me know if i should ask this question more clearly